# Mail sending in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a enquiry form that is to be submitted by subscribers/clients and the email is supposed to be redirected to us. I have following mail configurations in .env file :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=malakar@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=abcdef
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

In my controller:

```
$email = $request->email;
    Mail::send('Email.test', ['name' => $request->name, 'email' => $request->email, 'msg' => $request->message], function ($message) use ($email) {
        $message->from($email);
        $message->to('malakar@gmail.com')->subject('Enquiry For Booking');
    });
```

This doesn't work I guess. Mail is sent from the account that is configured in .env file.

How is 'from' method supposed to work?

Comment: Mail will be sent from that account configured in  `.env` file. You actually want the details of the sender which you can receive in a body of message

Comment: @NaumanZafar thanks for the reply.. Is there any other way to send repliable mails? :)

Comment: One way could be that along with sending an email save the user message details (email, message etc.) to your database also and then write something to reply to those emails saved.

Comment: @NaumanZafar thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $message->replyTo('someemail@mail.com').
In this case when somebody reply to the email it will use these email address.